# Python Regex matching word inside words

Tags: python, regex

I've been reading the documentation but can't find what I'm looking for.

I'm simply trying to match `foo` inside `foobar` but can't seem to see how to do it. Any guidance would be helpful!

Comment: Always found this helpful for creating regex: https://txt2re.com/

Comment: `>>> m = re.search('foo','foobar')`
`>>> m.group()`
`'foo'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parenthesis 
Like 
`re.findall("(foo)bar","foobar foogy woogy")`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `re` just use string evaluation.

```
string = 'Hello world my name is foobar'
for i in string.split():
    if 'foo' in i:
        print('{} contains {}'.format(i, 'foo'))
```

Answer (score 1):

use the `in` operator, it will check if `'foo'` is a substring of `'foobar'`

```
>>> 'foo' in 'foobar'
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall("[a-zA-Z]*(foo)[a-zA-Z]*", "foobar")
['foo']
```

Or if you want the whole string

```
>>> re.findall("[a-zA-Z]*foo[a-zA-Z]*", "foobar")
['foobar']
```